# Replace a rectangle with an Image in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame and python in general. Today I was trying to code a simplified TopDown movement. I did it and it runs without any issues. But i've got a problem anyways: The "player" is a rectangle but I want him to be an image or something like that. Is there a way to 'convert' a rect to an image?

Oh, and here's the code if you need it, I made it from another question I asked a week ago (or a bit longer):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption("TopDown")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = pygame.Rect(350, 350, 40, 60)
vel = 1

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.x += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * vel
    player.y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * vel
            
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), player)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the image with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load). This function returns a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object:

```py
player_image = pygame.image.load("player_image.png").convert_alpha()
player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = (350, 350))
```

Put the *Surface* onto the display with [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blits):

```py
win.blit(player_image, player_rect)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption("TopDown")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player_image = pygame.image.load("player_image.png").convert_alpha()
player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = (350, 350))
vel = 5

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player_rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * vel
    player_rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * vel
            
    win.fill((64, 238, 255))
    win.blit(player_image, player_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```